# Swap arrays of different sizes

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures, vector, bigdata

I needed to swap the contents of two `std::string` arrays of different sizes. Using `std::vector<std::string>` to use the `swap` vector method was the answer for other questions like this one, but using a vector was undesirable in my situation, since the swap is the only moment the arrays might have had their lengths changed - this function would only be called once, at initialization, other than that they'd be (very big) fixed length arrays. At the end I re-structured my code to avoid the swap in the first place, but I'm curious if it's feasible. I tried the following, where `n` is the length of `a` and `m` the length of `b`, but it segfaults.

```
void swap_strarr(std::string *a, std::string *b, int n, int m) {
    int i;
    std::string *tmp;
    tmp = new std::string[n];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        tmp[i] = a[i];
    }
    delete []a;
    a = new std::string[m];
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        a[i] = b[i];
    }
    delete []b;
    b = new std::string[n];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        b[i] = tmp[i];
    }
    delete []tmp;
}
```

I first tried without the `delete`s on `a` and `b`. I also tried using `std::string**`, which shouldn't even work - and it didn't.

So... is it possible? Or, had I done the swap, should I just use `std::vector` even though they're fixed size arrays (apart from the swap) and a few million elements long?

Comment: Have you tried [`std::string::swap`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/swap/)?

Comment: You can't really swap arrays, period.

Comment: I see no reason to trouble yourself with raw pointers just because the size is fixed. There's no penalty for not changing the size of a vector. If the interface troubles you, the ability to resize raw pointer "arrays" should as well.

Comment: `a` will not be modified for the caller, so the `a` from the caller will pointer to chunk pointer...

Comment: @Alex Your code also has a major flaw in that if the call to allocate for `b` fails, you've not only got a memory leak for `tmp`, you've got an incomplete swap.  Heck, if any call to `new` fails (except for the one with `tmp`) you have a memory leak.

Comment: > using a vector was undesirable in my situation, since the swap is the only moment the arrays might have had their lengths changed

So? Vector uses an array as an underlying container, so it adds precisely ZERO overhead to use it. If you are really worried about it, use std::array instead.

Comment: "using a vector was undesirable" - neverless, that's the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply something like:

```
std::string* tmp = a;
a = b;
b = tmp;
```

or even simpler (thanks juanchopanza):

```
std::swap(a, b);
```

Comment: Why not? Because that would just swap the local pointers, not the arrays. (Swapping the arrays is, of course, impossible.)